# What happened to Other resource type in the DSTU2?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is other resource type still supported in DSTU2? I can't seem to find it in the following resource list:
http://www.hl7.org/fhir/2015May/resourcelist.html
Thanks.
Mehmood.

Answer (score 1):

It's been renamed to Basic.  (Whenever you see something that seems to have disappeared, consult the "Version History" link which appears on the home page as well as in the footer of each page.)